# Bonsai automatic indexing

Tags: mongodb, heroku, express, elasticsearch, bonsai-elasticsearch

I use MongoDb for storage with an express, Heroku-hosted app.

I would like to provide search capabilities to some MongoDb collections, using ElasticSearch via the [Bonsai](https://bonsai.io/) Heroku add-on.

*However, according to the [Bonsai faq](https://bonsai.io/faq), Elasticsearch River plugins are not supported.*

How can I automatically re-index my MongoDb collections (when a MongoDb document is created/updated/deleted) on Bonsai, using custom mapping, if I cannot use [elasticsearch-river-mongodb](http://elasticsearch-river-mongodb)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer by Bonsai support:

```
- You could always set up a script with a curl command to index the MongoDB collections, then use cron to run the script at regular intervals.
- You could also use an Elasticsearch client to index collections in some cases.
```

---

So I made a *reindex* script inspired by [Elaster](https://github.com/likeastore/elaster), which can:

- either be called at regular intervals with [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron);
- or be called on demand, following event detection; to trigger events I use [mongo-oplog](https://github.com/cayasso/mongo-oplog), like so:

  ```
  oplog.on('insert', function (doc) {
    reindex();
  });
  ```